autofs shows resources but returns `file not found` when I try to access them
For some time now autofs stopped working properly, I've configure it to mount samba shared exposed on my raspberry running DietPi.
My conf is really simple:
/etc/auto.master.d/dietpi-rpi1.autofs :
/mnt/smb    /etc/auto.smb --timeout=60

The auto.smb is a script:
#!/bin/bash

# This file must be executable to work! chmod 755!

# Automagically mount CIFS shares in the network, similar to
# what autofs -hosts does for NFS.

# Put a line like the following in /etc/auto.master:
# /cifs  /etc/auto.smb --timeout=300
# You'll be able to access Windows and Samba shares in your network
# under /cifs/host.domain/share

# "smbclient -L" is used to obtain a list of shares from the given host.
# In some environments, this requires valid credentials.

# This script knows 2 methods to obtain credentials:
# 1) if a credentials file (see mount.cifs(8)) is present
#    under /etc/creds/$key, use it.
# 2) Otherwise, try to find a usable kerberos credentials cache
#    for the uid of the user that was first to trigger the mount
#    and use that.
# If both methods fail, the script will try to obtain the list
# of shares anonymously.

get_krb5_cache() {
    cache=
    uid=${UID}
    for x in $(ls -d /run/user/$uid/krb5cc_* 2>/dev/null); do
        if [ -d "$x" ] && klist -s DIR:"$x"; then
        cache=DIR:$x
            return
        fi
    done
    if [ -f /tmp/krb5cc_$uid ] && klist -s /tmp/krb5cc_$uid; then
        cache=/tmp/krb5cc_$uid
        return
    fi
}

key="$1"
opts="-fstype=cifs"

for P in /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin
do
    if [ -x $P/smbclient ]
    then
        SMBCLIENT=$P/smbclient
        break
    fi
done

[ -x $SMBCLIENT ] || exit 1

creds=/etc/creds/$key
if [ -f "$creds" ]; then
    opts="$opts"',uid=$UID,gid=$GID,credentials='"$creds"
    smbopts="-A $creds"
else
    get_krb5_cache
    if [ -n "$cache" ]; then
        opts="$opts"',multiuser,cruid=$UID,sec=krb5i'
        smbopts="-k"
        export KRB5CCNAME=$cache
    else
        opts="$opts"',guest'
        smbopts="-N"
    fi
fi

$SMBCLIENT $smbopts -gL "$key" 2>/dev/null| awk -v "key=$key" -v "opts=$opts" -F '|' -- '
    BEGIN   { ORS=""; first=1 }
    /Disk/  {
          if (first)
            print opts; first=0
          dir = $2
          loc = $2
          # Enclose mount dir and location in quotes
          print " \\\n\t \"/" dir "\"", "\"://" key "/" loc "\""
        }
    END     { if (!first) print "\n"; else exit 1 }
    '

I also have a /etc/creds/dietpi-rpi1 containing my credentials in the form
username=.......
password=.......
If I cd into /mnt/smb/dietpi-rpi1 I can actually see the resources:
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 May 25 17:19  daniele
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 May 25 17:19 'print$'
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 May 25 17:19  shares

but if I try to cd into them I get a "No such file or directory" error (neither as root):
bash: cd: shares/: No such file or directory

I can manually mount and browse them.

Can you show us /etc/auto.smb? And what is creds/dietpi-rpi1? Where is the creds directory? Can you ls a directory under /mnt/smb/dietpi-rpi1?
